# How can I create an instance of a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I need to create an instance of a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. I cannot create an empty constructor within the class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`, so how do I initialize the instance in my other class?

For example, I cannot just do this:

```java
MyDatabaseManager myDatabaseManager = new MyDatabaseManager();
```

because the constructor of `MyDatabaseManager` requires a context, name, factory, and version as parameters, but I also get an error when I try to create an empty construcor within the `MyDatabaseManager` class, because it extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

So how would I go about creating an instance of that class in another class?

Comment: Why do you want to use an empty constructor?

Comment: So I can create the instance of the class without having to pass in the context, name, factory, and version parameters.

Comment: `SQLiteOpenHelper` needs these values to do its job.